# Declare textView in program containing multiple xml files (android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm just beginning to learn to develop android apps, using eclipse.

I created multiple .xml files and put a textView in each one. However, they are all called textView1. So in my main activity, if I want to declare a textView, like

```
TextView hello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

how will the compiler know which xml file to look at? How should I specify?

Comment: In setcontentview(layout); you need to specify the layout in which the textview1 is present.

Answer (score 0):

In the method

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

here you are setting one xml to your activity.

and when you are declaring

```
TextView hello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

so textview1 of main.xml will called.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a file in the `onCreate` using `setContentView`, it knows which xml file you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to worry about that. *Android* system is smart enough to find the exact id.Android gets the view id from the layout you specify in `setContentView()` method.
So feel free to use same id in other xml layout file.

#### Note:--

```
 In same xml file, id of any View should be unique.
```